# sencha touch 2.0 : How to create a form from a model

Tags: forms, sencha-touch

Is there an easy way to automatically generate a form panel (I mean the fields and the values), given a model and a store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an instance of your model, then iterate through the empty `data` object adding input fields to the form panel, this code won't work because the Form.Panel isn't added to anything but you should be able to get the idea.

```
var objModel = Ext.create('app.model.objModel'),
    fp = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel');

Ext.iterate(objModel.data, function (item) {
    fp.add({xtype: 'textfield', name: item, label: item});
}
```